# Write the API to the background server for forwarding, then deploy to the server, some API swill not be available, What is the reason 1010?

Tags: api, iot, tuya

I write the API to the background server for forwarding, there is no problem to access under the domain name ending with cn, then deploy to the server, and finally change the domain name in the server forwarding API to the end with us, as long as it is in the form of carrying body request parameters, The API will not be available. What is the reason 1010?

Answer (score 0):

The tokens of the three districts are obtained independently and cannot be mixed. For example, the token obtained in China is not used as a token in the request header in America.